# Need an update query for temporary table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table `#Temp_SalesOrder` in a stored procedure `SP_SalesOrder` and it has 5 columns. I am using a cursor for looping this temp table insertion.

I am inserting values in this temp table (first 4 columns ) through another stored procedure `Sp_SalesOrderValues`. I need to update last column in this temp table as value selected in cursor variable. But I have no unique columns in temp table for where condition for update query. Insertion is happening row by row so I need to update this column value as row wise.

I am sharing my query I need to get the answer like the below structure but I am always getting 80 as entire column value ...

Please help ..

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_SalesOrder ') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Tbl_SalesOrderChildRef

CREATE TABLE #Temp_SalesOrder 
(
    Pk INT,
    ProductMasterId INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),               
    AllocatableQty NUMERIC(18, 0),
    SalesOrderSkuRate NUMERIC(18, 3) NULL
) 

-- Selecting SalesOrderSkuRate  using a select query
OPEN @curSalesOrderChild

FETCH NEXT FROM @curSalesOrderChild INTO @productMasterId, @Name, @SalesOrderSkuRate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Tbl_SalesOrderChildRef 
        EXEC Sp_SalesOrderValues
             @SkuMasterID = @productMasterId,
             @Name = @Name,
             @AllocatableQty = @AllocatableQty

    UPDATE #Tbl_SalesOrderChildRef 
    SET SalesOrderSkuRate = @SalesOrderSkuRate  ---Need a where condition for updating row by row now it updating last SalesOrderSkuRate to entire column that is my issue 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @curSalesOrderChild INTO @productMasterId, @Name, @AllocatableQty, @SalesOrderSkuRate
END

CLOSE @curSalesOrderChild
DEALLOCATE @curSalesOrderChild
```

Output is:

```
pk  ProductMasterId     Name    AllocatableQty  SalesOrderSkuRate 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   50                   A1       10                    25
2   81                   A2       20                    75
3   92                   A3       30                    80
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: So do what your comment says - apply a where clause. If you have no way of knowing which rows are inserted, then I suggest you change something - add the appropriate columns to the resultset of Sp_SalesOrderValues (meaningless name, BTW). If not you will need to change your logic to insert rows into a second table, update those rows, insert those updated rows into your final resultset table, and then truncate that second table. This is really a poor design

Comment: @SMor: What about non-violent language?

Comment: @Agnes: I'm a bit confused by your code. Is ```#Tbl_SalesOrderChildRef``` the same table as ```#Temp_SalesOrder``` (renaming in source code and not every occurrence changed) or are they different ones?

Comment: yes both temp table are same .. mistake from my side @Christoph